# OPENVPN TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to connect my client to my server but I get the error in subject. Googoling a while, I can confirm than TLS option is disabled on server/client

```
2016-09-18 14:26:23+0100 [-] OVPN 0 OUT: 'Sun Sep 18 13:26:23 2016 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]2.25.60.99:23734'
2016-09-18 14:26:25+0100 [-] OVPN 0 OUT: 'Sun Sep 18 13:26:25 2016 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]2.25.60.99:237
```

---SERVER--

```
...
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
...
```

--CLIENT--

```
...
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1
...
```

I have tried also to enable the feature and create the key but a that point I get

```
2016-09-18 11:38:45+0100 [-] OVPN 0 OUT: 'Sun Sep 18 10:38:45 2016
Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed'
2016-09-18 11:38:45+0100 [-] OVPN 0 OUT: 'Sun Sep 18 10:38:45 2016 TLS
Error: incoming packet authentication failed from
[AF_INET]2.25.60.99:22932'
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was running OpenVPN and OpenVPN GUI on the same node. Once disabled OpenVPN GUI I was able to connect my VPN

Comment: I'd suggest that you *accept* this answer so the question is not listed as unanswered.